# How to sort GET query according to the specified rules

Tags: python, django

I'm using url_replace to add GET query like below.

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):
    get_params = request.GET.copy()
    get_params[field] = value
    return get_params.urlencode()

<p>[ Category ]</p>
<ul>
    {% for cat in cats %}
    <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'category' cat.slug %}">{{ cat.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<p>[ Job Type ]</p>
<ul>
    {% for type_value, type_name in types %}
    <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'type' type_value %}">{{ type_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It arranges GET query every time clicks specified link. For example:

```
1)
current URL: /jobs/
click <a href="?{% url_replace request 'category' cat.slug %}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
URL changes: /jobs/?category=cat.slug
then click <a href="?{% url_replace request 'type' type_value %}">{{ type_name }}</a>
URL changes: /jobs/?category=cat.slug&type=type_value

2)
current URL: /jobs/
click <a href="?{% url_replace request 'type' type_value %}">{{ type_name }}</a>
URL changes: /jobs/?type=type_value
then click <a href="?{% url_replace request 'category' cat.slug %}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
URL changes: /jobs/?type=type_value&category=cat.slug
```

But I want to sort these GET queries always category first and next is type.

```
always: /jobs/?category=cat.slug&type=type_value
not: /jobs/?type=type_value&category=cat.slug
```

How can I do this?

Comment: URL query params are unordered by definition. You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. I recommend [reading this](http://xyproblem.info/) and then going through the Django docs to understand what kind of design pattern you should really be following.

Comment: I am not sure how to help you directly with this because as Andre said they're unordered. However, I also think you should construct the urls in your templates a bit differently, or handle the ordering on your backend.